# Animate in and out a widget when some data changes in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a widget that is displaying data, which changes over time, i'd like for that old data to fade out, then fade in new data when its available (passed in by the parent).
How can i achieve this?

Comment: see `AnimatedCrossFade` / `AnimatedSwitcher`

Comment: but it seems that `AnimatedSwitcher` is easier to use

Comment: am not switching the component. it's the same component, just changing the model

Comment: i know its the same component: thats why i said that `AnimatedSwitcher`  is easier to use

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help u:

```
AnimatedOpacity(
  opacity: _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  child: Text('Hello World!),
);
```